# Limiting sFTP access

Tags: permissions

A Raspberry pi is configured with OSMC behind a firewall.  The router forwards WAN port 21 traffic to port 22 of the rPi.  A guest user has been configured.  Assume the username is guest and though not hostile, but 'inquisitive'

The user will be instructed to use WinSCP to get / put files to the home directory.  Is there a simple command to prevent the guest from:

1. from roaming through the raspberry pi's directories?
2. issuing commands from the command line, other than those necessary to sFTP read & write to/home/guest?

The goal is to allow the guest to sFTP (read / write) files in /home/guest and no more.  Maybe the right question to ask: is what is the minimum set of commands are needed to meet the goal? and how to lock down guest commands so that only those commands are enabled.

Any attempts to sharpen the question are appreciated.  Thank you